# VSO Release Management - Tests will not run

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ms-release-management

I have a VSO release management definition in which I'm deploying a cloud service and then running some tests. The deployment executes without issues, but then the tests don't run, I recieve the following message in the logs:

Warning: No test is available in **My DLL Path**. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Now, the strange thing is that this release is triggered by a build, which runs exactly the same set of tests and they all run happily.

I've included a runsettings file specifying the framework version (based on some SO posts I found from a year ago with a similar issue) but its made no difference. Been messing with this for nearly 2 days now with no progress. Any suggestions happily accepted!

Comment: What test framework are you using? What task are you using to run the tests?

Comment: Its the defaults: MsTest and the Visual Studio Test task

Comment: which task are you using? Be exact there are several tasks: [VSTest](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/visual-studio-test) or [Run Functional Test](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/run-functional-tests). What are the input to the task you pass over during Build and during Release? Any difference? Are the DLL copied where you run the test? Are you aware where you actually are running the test?

Comment: Are your test assemblies in your drop folder for the build?

Comment: Did you use the same agent for build and release? What're steps of build and release definitions? Can you share the detail build and release log here or on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 0):

Arrrrgh! So it turns out, if I deleted the whole project, created it again and added my tests again, it just works. Gremlins apparently!

Admins, if this needs to be deleted, go ahead